# Can we save files in local when developing custom functions?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I am following [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions) to try custom functions.

First I put `customfunctions.js` and `customfunctions.html` in my local folder, and then replace `https://<INSERT-URL-HERE>` in the manifest file with their path: I tried `\\SOFTTIMUR9FDC\Users\SoftTimur\tmp\EXCEL-CUSTOM-FUNCTIONS` and `\\Mac\Home\tmp\EXCEL-CUSTOM-FUNCTIONS\`, but I could not see any application in `SHARED FOLDER` in Excel.

Then, I put these 2 files on a website, and then replace `https://<INSERT-URL-HERE>` in the manifest file with their https address. Now, it worked; I could see the application in `SHARED FOLDER` in Excel and the custom functions worked.

So is it expected? In other words, when we test custom functions, we could not save these files in LOCAL; we have to save them in a website?

PS: when we develop a normal excel add-in, there is no problem to save the source files in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to host your customfunctions.html file locally, yes. From your description, it sounds like there's something wrong with how you're deploying the manifest, or with the manifest itself. Verify that your only change was the URL for those files, and that it worked properly otherwise.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for confirming this. Since [we cannot submit add-ins with custom functions at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039474/submit-add-ins-with-custom-functions), I will come back to adding custom functions later...