# Submit add-ins with custom functions

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview), it is mentioned that

> The following features aren't yet supported in the Developer Preview.
>
> ... ...
>
> Publishing add-ins to the Office Store or Office 365 centralized
>   deployment that use custom functions.

I just want to make sure it means that at the moment we cannot submit to Office Store any add-in that has custom functions; what we can do is only internally deploying add-ins with custom functions, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of that guidance in the documentation is correct. i.e., an add-in that uses custom functions cannot currently be published to the Office Store or via Office 365 centralized deployment.

For information about other ways to publish an add-in, see [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish).

Comment: I just got an email which told me "Custom functions are officially in Preview! Try them! more info in https://aka.ms/customfunctions". But on that page `Deployment via the Office 365 Admin Portal and AppSource are not yet enabled.` is still there. So today developers still can NOT submit add-ins with custom functions?

Answer (score 0):

Was meaning to reply back to this, but add-ins with custom functions are available to be submitted to the Office Store, as announced here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-extensibility-build-2019/

Note: Centralized Deployment is still being deployed through all tenants and that will take a few more weeks to complete.

Comment: Nevermind, my answer is a duplicate of this one I already posted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239311/submit-add-ins-with-custom-functions-update